# Is there a way to get amp volume using CEC?

Tags: hdmi, osmc, cec-client

I noticed there is volup and voldown in `cec-client` commands. But how do I know the current level to make the Raspberry Pi adjust it? Or is it possible to set a percentage?

I used scan, but it didn't notice that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cec-client allows you to pipe cec frames, such as `echo "tx 20:71" | cec-client RPI -s -d 1`. http://www.cec-o-matic.com/ has a list of supported features and frame composer/decomposer. https://blog.gordonturner.com/2016/12/14/using-cec-client-on-a-raspberry-pi/ has more information on how to use these with cec-client.

Comment: I played with this before but never figured out commands to set or get volumes on my onkyo amp.  I guess the best way is to use an IR blaster instead of cec to automate control.

Comment: http://www.cec-o-matic.com/ has to one of those weirdest sites ever, I can't figure how to use it.
Does "tx 20:71" means return the current volume setting?

I have yet to find a blog for humans to tell me how to set TV volume to 50%  this non-sense CEC bizarre protocol is flying over my head and unnecessarily boiling my blood.:)

Comment: The site is quite weird, but I've mostly figured it out after playing around. If you enter `20:71` in the text box and hit the down-arrow next to it, the site will select the description underneath the text box. In particular, the first hex digits are the source and target. The remaining bytes are the message.`71` is the `<Give Audio Status>` byte which requests that the destination report its audio status back to the source. If you select a source, target, and message and hit the up-arrow, the bytes of the frame will appear in the text box.